# How to Create dynamic Views in Firebase onDataChange

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying the read from Firebase and since the data Keys are not the same all the time, I wanted to create dynamic Views:

```
"CategoriesInModifiers" : {
    "01" : {
      "01" : true,
      "02" : true,
      "04" : true,
      "05" : true
    },
    "02" : {
      "01" : true,
      "04" : true
    },
    "03" : {
      "03" : true,
      "04" : true,
      "05" : true
    },
    "04" : {
      "02" : true,
      "04" : true
    }
  },
```

I then need to call another Firebase reference to get the relative categories.
My point is that how to create dynamic views like checkboxes inside onDataChange as I can't use context nor "this" i get error!

It could be  much easier if i have used Firestore from the start but Firestore just came out last week and i am done with this project.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a regular dynamic view inside of the onDataChange. And then keep adding that view into the parent layout;

```
View myView = new View();
parentLayout.addView(myView);
```